# Exposing Redux with Webpack 2

Tags: webpack, redux, webpack-2

I'm migrating Webpack from version 1 to 2 in a project i'm working on, and one of the builds I have is for a dependencies file, in which i'm exposing all the dependencies on the `Window` using webpack's expose-loader.

It works fine except for Redux which doesn't gets exposed.

These are the relevant parts of my configuration:

```
entry: {
    dependencies: [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'react-router',
        'redux',
        'react-redux',
        'redux-thunk',
        'es6-promise',
        'isomorphic-fetch'
    ]
},
```

and:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: [
                'babel-loader'
            ],
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('react'),
            use: 'expose-loader?React'
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('react-dom'),
            use: 'expose-loader?ReactDOM'
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('react-router'),
            use: 'expose-loader?ReactRouter'
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('redux'),
            use: 'expose-loader?Redux'
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('react-redux'),
            use: 'expose-loader?ReactRedux'
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('redux-thunk'),
            use: 'expose-loader?ReduxThunk'
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('isomorphic-fetch'),
            use: 'expose-loader?fetch'
        }
    ]
}
```

Also here's my babel presets:

```
"presets": [
    "react",
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-2"
],
```

When I run the build I get this output:

[image]

Note that Redux is added by functions.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like webpack can't automatically resolve redux and other modules with a simple string reference like you have in an entries list.

Putting `console.log` into `expose-loader/index.js` caused this output. which shows that Redux and others not even get through expose loader.

[image]

Changing entries list to this, should solve the problem.

```
   entry: [
        require.resolve('redux'),
        require.resolve('react'),
        require.resolve('react-dom'),
        require.resolve('react-router'),
        require.resolve('react-redux'),
        require.resolve('redux-thunk'),
        require.resolve('es6-promise'),
        require.resolve('isomorphic-fetch')
    ],
```